# using axios with promise API

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks, es6-promise

I am using a promise based hook in a React app to fetch async data from an API.

I am also using a Axios, a promise based http client to call the API.

Is it an anti-pattern to use a promise based client inside another promise? The below code does not seem to work.

```
const getData = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const url = "/getData";
    axios.get(url)
      .then(function(response) {
        resolve(response);
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        reject(error);
      });
  });

const useAsync = (asyncFunction) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(null);

  const execute = useCallback(() => {
    setPending(true);
    setValue(null);
    setError(null);
    return asyncFunction()
      .then(response => setValue(response))
      .catch(error => setError(error))
      .finally(() => setPending(false));
  }, [asyncFunction]);

  useEffect(() => {
      execute();
  }, [execute]);

  return { execute, pending, value, error };
};
};

const RidesList = () => {
  const {
    pending,
    value,
    error,
  } = useAsync(getData);
```

Comment: Is there any reason as to why you are not using `async await` ?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I need to look up async await. I thought using the same hook for every call would make the code readable.

I am getting no errors I only see that the promise is pending indefinitely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh man. I think you have a fundamental misunderstanding about how Promises work.
First, axios already returns a `Promise` by default. So your whole first function of `getData` can be reduced to:

```js
const getData = () => {
  const url = "/getData"
  return axios.get(url)
}
```

But the meat of your code seems to indicate you want a querable Promise - so you can check the status of it for whatever reason. Here's an example of how you would do it, adapted from [this snippet](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/317/how-to-check-if-a-javascript-promise-has-been-fulfilled-rejected-or-resolved):

```js
function statusPromiseMaker(promise) {
  if (promise.isResolved) return promise
  let status = {
    pending: true,
    rejected: false,
    fulfilled: false
  }
  let result = promise.then(
      resolvedValue => {
        status.fulfilled = true
        return resolvedValue
      },
      rejectedError => {
        status.rejected = true
        throw rejectedError
      }
    )
    .finally(() => {
      status.pending = false
    })

  result.status = () => status
  return result
}
```

In this way, you can then do something like `let thing = statusPromiseMaker(getData())` and if you look up `thing.status.pending` you'll get `true` or `false` etc...

I didn't actually run what's above, I may have forgotten a bracket or two, but hopefully this helps.

I have to admit - I haven't seen anything like this ever used in the wild. I am interested in knowing what you're actually trying to accomplish by this.

Answer (score 1):

Axios itself returns a promise but if you want to make a custom class having your custom logic after each API call then you can use interceptors I was having the same requirement and this is how I am returning promises after applying my custom logic on each API call.

Interceptors will get executed separately after and before each request you made so we can simply use them if we want to modify our request or response.

here is my working solution have a look at it.

```
callApi = (method, endpoint, params) => {

    this.apiHandler.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
        config.method = method
        config.url = config.baseURL + endpoint
        config.params = params
        return config
    })

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.apiHandler.interceptors.response.use((config) => {
            if (config.status == 200) {
                resolve(config.data)
            } else {
                reject(config.status)
            }
            // return config
        }, error => reject(error))

        this.apiHandler()
    })
}
```

Below is the code to call this function

```
helper.callApi("get", "wo/getAllWorkOrders").then(d => {
    console.log(d)
})
```